# What is the free loop space $\mathcal{L}M$ of a manifold of a manifold $M$ for which the energy functional has no critical points?

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory, loop-spaces

What is the free loop space $\mathcal{L}M$ of a manifold $M$ for which $E:LM\to\mathbb{R}$ for $E:\gamma\mapsto\int_{S^1}\|\dot\gamma(t)\|^2dt$ has no non-degenerate critical points? Is it simply the empty set (is this possible)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think $E$ is always critical for trival loops $\gamma(t) =  p \in M, \; \forall t$.  I think $\gamma$ is always critical if $E(\gamma) = 0$.  What do you think about this?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, the existence critical points at level $0$, i.e. constant geodesics $\gamma(t)=p$, for $p\in M$ for all $t\in S^1$, means that $M=\mathcal{L}M$. @RobertLewis

Comment: This is a good question, I think, ***endorsed (+1)***, but it's pretty broad.  How do you want to characterize $\mathcal LM$?  In raw terms, the free loop space $\mathcal LM$ is, after all, $\mathcal LM$.  What kind of specific characterization are you looking for?

Comment: The gist of my comment(s) is that $E(\gamma)$ *always* has some critical points.  One for each $p \in M$, at least, taking $\gamma(t) = p$.  We might need to look at something like homotopy classes of free loops to get more details.

Comment: Of course such constant geodesics are degenerate. I define $\mathcal{L}M$ by the space of smooth loops in $M$, $C^{\infty}(S^1,M)$. @RobertLewis

Comment: I accept your definition, provisionally, but my question still remains:  what kind of description do we want?  Saying $\mathcal LM = M$ might also be problematic because the topologies on $\mathcal LM$ and $M$ might be pretty different.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean CW vs Hilbert description? I believe if we let $\Lambda M=\{\gamma:E[\gamma]=0\}$ then it is true that $\Lambda M=M$ if there are no non-degenerate critical points. @RobertLewis

Comment: Sort of; that's getting at it.  Probably I'm more engaged by description as an infinite dimensional Hilbert manifold if such is valid; I know standard Morse theory talks about CW description.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes!

Comment: This is true for instance on a sphere, where geodesics always arise in families (the great circles, traversed some number of times). These are still Morse-Bott (there are 'critical submanifolds' and the energy function has non-degenerate Hessian on the normal space to these submanifolds). I imagine there are plenty of cases where even this is false, other than at the trivial loops. But actually computing such an example is probably unreasonable, as it entails both computing all the geodesics on a manifold as well as their Jacobi fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy functional on the *free* loop space $LM$ only has degenerate critical points if $M$ is not zero dimensional. Of course all the constant loops are degenerate critical points (the critical set is a copy of $M$)

Here is the reason why all non-constant closed geodesic are degenerate:

There is a non-trivial action of the circle $S^1$ on the free loop space that leaves the energy functional invariant. If $\gamma:S^1\rightarrow M$ is a loop we define a new loop $s\cdot \gamma:S^1\rightarrow M$ by $c\cdot \gamma(t)=\gamma(t+s)$. If $\gamma$ is a non-constant loop then $c\cdot \gamma$ is also a non-constant loop (and different for most values of $c$!).

The functional $E$ is invariant under this action. Thus for any closed geodesic $\gamma$ for almost all $c$ the loop $c\cdot \gamma$ is also a closed geodesic (this is just a reparametrization). This shows that there cannot be isolated critical points. The best one can hope for is that the critical points come in $S^1$ families. I think it is true that this is true for a generic set of metrics, although I cannot give a reference from the top of my head.

You might wonder if there are manifolds without non-trivial closed geodesics. There is a Theorem of Lyusternik and Fet that this can only occur for non-compact manifolds (I take my manifolds without boundary here). Euclidean space is a simple example of a manifold without closed geodesics.